# keyframe transform translate not working on safari and edge

Tags: css, animation, svg, safari, translate

I have an animation that works fine on Firefox, Chrome but does not work on Safari and Edge. 
The animation objects are contained in a svg file loaded with js.
The idea is that elements appear in succession at the center of screen and then move up to their intended final location.

An example of the css I use to achieve this is:

```
@-webkit-keyframes move-you {
    0% { 
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate(450px,400px);
                transform: translate(450px,400px);

    }
    50% { 
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translate(450px,400px);
        transform: translate(450px,400px);
    }
    100% { 
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translate(450px,222px);
        transform: translate(450px,222px);

    }
}
@keyframes move-you {
    0% { 
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate(450px,400px);
                transform: translate(450px,400px);
    }
    50% { 
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translate(450px,400px);
                transform: translate(450px,400px);
    }
    100% { 
        opacity: 1;
       -webkit-transform: translate(450px,222px);
               transform: translate(450px,222px);

   }
}

.svgLoaded #you { 
-webkit-animation: move-you 1s ease-in 3s; 
        animation: move-you 1s ease-in 3s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
}
```

So, this works fine on Firefox and Chrome but the translation does not happen in Safari and Edge. Not a massive problem if large screen are used as everything is still visible,
( [you can see example here](http://www.bright-blue.ch/) )
but it means that I cannot translate items to where I want them on a small screen.
I have been stack on this for more than a day, the only answer I found was about missing brackets but I checked my code and all brackets are balanced. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would probably work:

```
@-webkit-keyframes move-you {
    0% { 
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate(450px,400px);
    }
    50% { 
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translate(450px,400px);
    }
    100% { 
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translate(450px,222px);
    }
}
@keyframes move-you {
    0% { 
        opacity: 0;
                transform: matrix(1,0,0, 1,0,0, 450, 400);
    }
    50% { 
        opacity: 1;
                transform: translate(1,0,0, 1,0,0, 450, 400);
    }
    100% { 
        opacity: 1;
               transform: translate(1,0,0, 1,0,0, 450, 222);

   }
}

.svgLoaded #you { 
-webkit-animation: move-you 1s ease-in 3s; 
        animation: move-you 1s ease-in 3s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
}
```

Comment: but I think you can improve that by animating the position properties:
x & y

Comment: This is not working. (Actually the standard @keyframes  always work, it is the -webkit-transform that does not work)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of problems with animating SVGs on different browsers. They all work different.

Here are some of the problems with creating consistent animations with SVGs:

- **IE** and **Opera** don't honor CSS transforms at all on SVG elements. Instead, you must assign the value to the *transform* **attribute**.
- **Firefox** didn't honor %-based origins in early versions (in latest versions it does).
- Zooming in **Safari** breaks the sync between %-based and px-based origins.
- Firefox doesn't recognize keyword-based origins like "right bottom", and Safari alters them when the zoom is anything but 100%.
- In all browsers, px-based origins are measured differently for SVG elements than other DOM elements (see below).

quotation of document on SVG transformations in [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/svg-animation-on-css-transforms/)

I found that using libraries like TweenMax do a pretty good work with almost all the browsers.
Of course there are some specific ways you should animate some of the properties so that they can work on IE 11. Few of them:
 - Circle radius
 - transitions

You can check the tips and tricks for the tool in [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/svg-animation-on-css-transforms/#article-header-id-4):

Comment: Your information is out of date: Firefox has honoured % based origins since version 43 for instance.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time Искрен, but all this does not help me. My problem is not that items are moved to different places with different browsers but rather that translate does not seem to work at all with safari and edge when applied to svg objects. Any idea how I might get that to work?